# Строчная или прописная?

Tags: орфография

Здравствуйте!
Хотелось бы разобраться: мероприятие Dubai World Cup чаще всего по-русски употребляется как "Кубок Дубая по скачкам". Если не брать в кавычки название, как будет правильно: "Д(д)убайский Кубок"?
Этот же вопрос интересует относительно сочетаний "М(м)иланская/П(п)арижская Неделя моды", например.
Спасибо

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Дубайский (мировой) кубок" скорее всего. И то если предполагать, что "Дубайский" - часть названия. Причин для напиания "кубок" с заглавной при таком порядке слов я не вижу никаких. Особенно если есть прилагательное.
Аналогично и "Миланская неделя моды".

Хотя данный случай действительно спорен, т.к. не совсем понятно, что считать собственно названием, т.е. входит ли в него слово "дубайский" или это обычное прилагательное. Но что удивительно, последнее время именно так стали писать в СМИ. Даже в наш век тотальной безграмотности журналистов манера копировать английский с его заглавными в каждом слове названия постепенно изживает себя. И это не может не радовать.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Слово "кубок" — это часть названия, отсюда следует, полагаю, что его надо писать с заглавной http://gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search_answer/?s=%EA%F3%E1%EE%EA+%EC%E8%F0%E0 А вот что касается д(Д)убайский/м(М)иланский, так и не понимаю... На той же грамоте встретила совет: два вопроса, два ответа. Не могу соотнести между собой эти два ответа http://gramota.ru/spravka/buro/search_answer/?s=%ED%E5%E4%5%EB%FF+%EC%EE%E4%FB

Comment: прошу прощения, не в курсе, можно ли здесь оставлять ссылки с других ресурсов. Просто разобраться хочется)

Comment: В русском языке в названиях с заглавной пишется только первой слово названия. Все остальные слова, если они представляют собой имя нарицательное в обычном значении, нормативно пишутся со строчной. Я согласен с тем, что спортивные кубки в каком-то смысле - уникальные объекты и поэтому слово "кубок" может рассматриваться как часть названия, но оно не теряет при этом общего нарицательного значения. 
  
Ссылки тут разрешены. Во всяком случае никаких замечаний со стороны администрации ресурса никогда не было.

Comment: Я не вижу противоречия в ответах Грамоты. 
Во всех случаях с заглавной пишется только первое слово: "Неделя моды", но "Нью-йоркская неделя моды".

Comment: Ага, значит, в этом дело... Я-то это рассматривала не с точки зрения "первое слово" (тут все понятно, конечно), а насколько "официально" это название. То есть, если обычно (официально) оно зовется "Кубок Дубая", то тут все ясно, а "Дубайский кубок" — уже неформальное такое название, потому и вопрос возник. Но мысль Вашу поняла, спасибо большое!